# How to set checkbox columns in radgrid Telerik to enable drag select

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid, radgrid

In my telerik radgrid i have 2 checkbox columns named "Approved" and "Denied". How do i 'check' multiple checkboxes in each column by draging over the checkboxes? Please note I DO NOT want to select multiple entire rows but just multiple checkboxes in these respective columns by just dragging. 
Here is the aspx:

```
 <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="checkBoxYesColumn">
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"   />
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                 <asp:CheckBox  ID="cbYesHead2" runat="server" />
                                <cc1:MutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxExtender ID="mecbeYesHead" runat="server" TargetControlID="cbYesHead2"  />
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                             <ItemStyle ... HorizontalAlign="Center"   />
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                 <asp:CheckBox class="enforceAll" ID="cbYes2" runat="server"  />
                                    <cc1:MutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxExtender ID="mecbe1" runat="server" TargetControlID="cbYes2"  />
                             </ItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>                           
                        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="" UniqueName="ignoreCheckBoxYesColumn">
                             <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"  />

                             <ItemStyle  HorizontalAlign="Center"   />
                             <ItemTemplate>    
                                 <asp:CheckBox  ID="cbNo2" runat="server"  />
                                    <cc1:MutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxExtender ID="mecbe2" runat="server" TargetControlID="cbNo2" />
                             </ItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Here is the code behind in C#:

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)headerItem.FindControl("cbYesHead2");

                cb.Attributes.Add(...);
                AjaxControlToolkit.MutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxExtender mecbeYes = (AjaxControlToolkit.MutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxExtender)headerItem.FindControl("mecbeYesHead2");
                mecbeYes.Key = "head_" +...

cb = (CheckBox)headerItem.FindControl("cbNo2");
                cb.Attributes.Add(...);
                AjaxControlToolkit.MutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxExtender mecbeNo = (AjaxControlToolkit.MutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxExtender)headerItem.FindControl("mecbe2");
                mecbeNo.Key = "head_" + ...
```